# Regular expression for weight(kg) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Could someone please tell me where I made a mistake? I spent the last few hours trying to get this right but nothing I do works. I would like it to accept strings like 0; 0,04; 500,04; 20,014322104.... (pretty much every number from 0 to 800) and nothing like 00 or 50,250,00,15....

This is what I wrote: `[[0]{0,1}\d{0,1}[1-9]{0,2}]{1}\d*[[,.]{0,1}\d+]{0,1}\d*`

I know it's completely wrong but I started looking into regex just today and I really don't know how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Why not use number handling when you've numeric values ..?

Comment: is 1 to 800.000 the exact range or would be 821.12 ok as well (so anyting 3 digit number + optional decimals)

Comment: Just some redundancy nitpicks: `[0]` is identical to `0`, `{0,1}` is identical to `?`, and `{1}` is identical to not writing a quantifier at all.

Comment: Few questions here. I'm assuming `,` is the decimal point. So when you say `50,250,00,15` isn't valid, it's because it has multiple decimal points? The input, is it actually a string like `X; X; X` where `X` is a number or is it already separated `X` and `X` and `X`? Also, why is `00` invalid, because it's two `0`s in a row? Since you want everything between `0` and `800`, I'm assuming `-1` and `801` are invalid?

Comment: No, 812.12 would not be okay Patrick Artner. Thank you for telling me that CAustin. Yes, , is the decimal point. Yes, it is because it has multiple decimal points. By that input I meant possible numbers the user could put in (either only 0 or only 0,04....). Yes, I would like 00 put at the beginning (00,05...) to be invalid, simply because I'm a perfectionist and I feel like it looks weird... And yes, -1 and 801 are invalid @ctwheels. Thank you everyone for your responses.

Comment: This is how the regex engine reads your regex: `[[0]{0,1}` + `\d{0,1}` +  `[1-9]{0,2}` +  `]{1}` + `\d*` + `[[,.]{0,1}` + `\d+` + `]{0,1}` + `\d*`

Comment: So I just decided that I will ignore the 0 or 00 or 000... inputs to not make it too difficult to read and also I just don't know what to write for it to not do that. I also decided that I won't take 800 as the maximum (I only wanted to set it to that for people to not put in crazy big weights... But I guess it is not so important as long as it works... So I think I'll just leave it like this `[0]?[1-9]{0,2}\d*[,.]?\d+?\d*` Thank you everyone so much for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get the job done:

```
^(0|[1-9]\d*)(,\d+)?$
```

Explanation:

- `^` start of string
- `(0|[1-9]\d*)` a single zero, or a digit from 1-9 followed by any number of digits
- `(,\d+)?` Optionally a single comma followed by a set of one or more digits
- `$` end of string

Answer (score 0):

### Code

```js
var s = "0; 0,04; 500,04; 20,014322104; 00; 50,250,00,15; 801; 800; -1"
var a = s.split(";").map(function(i) {
  return i.replace(/\s+/, "")
})

a.forEach(function(v) {
  if (/^(?!0{2})\d+(?:,\d+)?$/.exec(v) !== null) {
    if (Number(v.replace(/,/, ".")) <= 800) {
      console.log(v)
    }
  }
})
```

---

### Explanation

Splits the string on `;` and removes all whitespace in each item it adds to the array. Iterates over the array and checks to see `if` it matches the format of `X` or `X,X` (where `X` is a number). `(?!0{2})` ensures it doesn't match `00` or `00,XX`.

The next `if` statement converts the string number to a number (after replacing `,` with `.` to maintain the decimal place when converting). It checks that number against `800` to ensure it's equal or below.

Comment: Thank you so much @ctwheels for helping but this is too difficult for me to read as I am only a beginner. I edited what I originally wrote in my text editor so it works.. somehow.. it is not what I originally wanted but that's okay as long as I understand what I'm writing:)

Answer (score 0):

This works

`/^(?:,\d+|(?:\d|[1-9]\d|[1-7]\d{2})(?:,\d*)?|800(?:,0*)?)(?:;\s*(?:,\d+|(?:\d|[1-9]\d|[1-7]\d{2})(?:,\d*)?|800(?:,0*)?))*$/`

https://regex101.com/r/lNYuwX/1
and
https://regex101.com/r/lNYuwX/2

Expanded:

```
 ^ 
 (?:

      , \d+                   #  - .99999
   |  
      (?:                     # 0 - 799.99999
           \d 
        |  [1-9] \d 
        |  [1-7] \d{2} 
      )
      (?: , \d* )?
   |  
      800                     # 800 
      (?: , 0* )?
 )
 (?:
      ;
      \s* 
      (?:

           , \d+                 
        |  
           (?:
                \d 
             |  [1-9] \d 
             |  [1-7] \d{2} 
           )
           (?: , \d* )?
        |  
           800                     
           (?: , 0* )?
      )


 )*
 $
```